# How to check the clicked button title is equal to the image name in uiimageview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uibutton

Here my code to show the 4 button titles which one image view, I want to show the clicked alert if clicked button title is equal to the UIImageview image. Here is my code,

```
 imageary=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"dear.jpg",@"donkey.jpg",@"elephant.jpg",@"fox.jpg",@"giraffe.jpg",@"goat.jpg",@"buffallo.jpg",@"bull.jpg",@"cow.jpg",@"crocodile.jpg", nil]; // declare array of names not images
 - (NSString *) convertToDisplayName:(NSString *)actual
 {
  return [actual stringByDeletingPathExtension]; //return image name without extension
 }
```

Button method

```
-(IBAction)methodset:(id)sender
{

int i=0;
for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
{
  if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
  {  
   mybutton = (UIButton *)view;
   if(mybutton.tag == 1||mybutton.tag == 2||mybutton.tag == 3||mybutton.tag == 4)
   {
     i = rand() % [imageary count]; // set random image
     animage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[imageary objectAtIndex:i]]; 
    name=[self convertToDisplayName:[imageary objectAtIndex:i]];
    [mybutton setTitle:name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSLog(@"current image name :%@",name);
    i++;

   }
  }
 }
}
```

Now im facing problem with

1. rand(), while shuffling the some values in the button are
   repeating. How can i shuflle the values without repeating and show in
   UIButton.
2. Where should I compare for the image name and clicked button title
   is equal or not. Please help me to resolve this issue. Please do the
   needful.

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop for the rand bit

```
while (i != mybutton.tag){
   i = rand() % [imageary count];
}
```

Just compare the imagery names and uibutton title after the if(mybutton.tag ...etc etc because you want it in the for loop right? also indent your code :P. makes it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([btn.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"imageName"])
```

according to your code

```
if ([btn.titleLabel.text isEqualToString: name])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it by changing the function like:

```
-(IBAction)methodset:(id)sender
{
  UIButton *mybutton = (UIButton *)sender;
  if(mybutton.tag == 1||mybutton.tag == 2||mybutton.tag == 3||mybutton.tag == 4)
  {
     for(int loop = 0; loop<4;loop++)
     {
        animage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[imageary objectAtIndex:i]]; 
        name=[self convertToDisplayName:[imageary objectAtIndex:i]];
        [mybutton setTitle:name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSLog(@"current image name :%@",name);
        if ([mybutton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:[imageary objectAtIndex:i]])
        {
             //titles equal
        }

        UIView *newView = [self.view viewWithTag:i];
        if([newView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
           UIButton *newButton = (UIButton *)newView;
           [newbutton setTitle:name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: only clicked button title only showing,and all button having the same value

Comment: wer is btn.title intilized ,or that it mybutton.title huh?

Comment: it showing  error  `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setTitle:forState:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x756a7b0'`

Comment: you have same tag for different view's other than buttons. That's the issue, you need to check whether it is a button or not. edited with that condition

Comment: Now also only clicked button only showing the title and after click all title showing the same

Comment: **all title showing the same** won't happen because the name variable  is changing in all iteration. I assume that all the four button have 4 different tags. If that's the case, then this won't occur !!!

Comment: i give the button tag value as 1,2,3,4 only then what is the prob

Comment: I can't figure it out what is the issue.

Comment: @Fazil: if you can give a sample project and requirement then I will check and fix the issue.