# Assign random title in UIbutton

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uibutton

My `application` is like related to quiz,In my view im having 1 image view and 4 `UIbuttons`, intially i have to load a image in `imageview` and assigning 4 button title in shuffled  manner,One of the button should be the current image name,If user clicks the button i want to show the next set of button title and new `image`

```
 -(IBAction)answersetting:(id)sender
{
int i=0;
UIButton *mybutton = (UIButton *)sender;
[mybutton addTarget:self action:@selector(submitGuess:)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
if(mybutton.tag == 1||mybutton.tag == 2||mybutton.tag == 3||mybutton.tag == 4)
{
           for(int loop = 0; loop<4;loop++)
    {
        animage.image=[UIImage  imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",[imageary objectAtIndex:i]]];
        name=[self convertToDisplayName:[imageary objectAtIndex:i]];
        [mybutton setTitle:name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSLog(@"current image name :%@",name);
        if ([mybutton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:[imageary objectAtIndex:i]])
        {
            //titles equal
            [self alertshow];
            i++;
        }

        UIView *newView = [self.view viewWithTag:i];
        if([newView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton *newButton = (UIButton *)newView;
            [newButton setTitle:name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
   }
 }
```

this fail to excute what i describe over above.What change should i made in my code?Please help to solve this issue

Comment: you used my answer of your previous question right :)


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284405/how-to-check-the-clicked-button-title-is-equal-to-the-image-name-in-uiimageview

Comment: @MidhunMP i used but the title are being shoowed only when i click,and all the button titles are same

Comment: no need to put the same question again and again this will not provide you any answer lol :)

Comment: i just the mean for any other option tats it @Wolvorin

Comment: but if some one has any they can give it on the same question you dont need to post it again as different question :)

Comment: @Martol1ni when i click the button the clicked button only showing the button title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a method for displaying image and setting the button title. And use another method for evaluating the guess result.

```
//This method display the image and buttons

-(void)displayImageAndButton:(int)pos
{
       animage.image=[UIImage  imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",[imageary objectAtIndex:pos]]];

        UIView *newView = [self.view viewWithTag:buttonTag1];
        if([newView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton *newButton = (UIButton *)newView;
            name=[self convertToDisplayName:[imageary objectAtIndex:pos++]];
            [newButton addTarget:self action:@selector(submitGuess:)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            [newButton setTitle:name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        newView = [self.view viewWithTag:buttonTag2];
        if([newView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton *newButton = (UIButton *)newView;
            name=[self convertToDisplayName:[imageary objectAtIndex:pos++]];
            [newButton addTarget:self action:@selector(submitGuess:)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            [newButton setTitle:name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        newView = [self.view viewWithTag:buttonTag3];
        if([newView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton *newButton = (UIButton *)newView;
            name=[self convertToDisplayName:[imageary objectAtIndex:pos++]];
            [newButton addTarget:self action:@selector(submitGuess:)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            [newButton setTitle:name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        newView = [self.view viewWithTag:buttonTag4];
        if([newView isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            UIButton *newButton = (UIButton *)newView;
            name=[self convertToDisplayName:[imageary objectAtIndex:pos++]];
            [newButton addTarget:self action:@selector(submitGuess:)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            [newButton setTitle:name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
 }

    //this method evaluates the answer

    - (IBAction)submitGuess:(id)sender
    {
      UIButton *mybutton = (UIButton *)sender;
      if ([mybutton.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:[imageary objectAtIndex:positionOfQuest]])
      {
                //titles equal
                [self alertshow];
      }
      positionOfQuest++;
      [self displayImageAndButton:positionOfQuest];
    }
```

Here buttonTag1,buttonTag2,buttonTag3 & buttonTag4 are tags of your button.

int the `viewDidLoad` declare a variable like:

```
static positionOfQuest = 0; //this for holding the question number
```

In IB add button tags and initialize them in `viewDidLoad` before calling the following method

and you need to call the method in `viewDidLoad` like:

```
[self displayImageAndButton:positionOfQuest];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like an easy way...

```
#include <stdlib.h>

NSMutableArray *quiz = [NSMutableArray alloc....];

for (int i=0; i<4; i++) { 
   int r = arc4random() % [quiz count];

   NSLog(@"%@", [quiz objectAtIndex:r]);
  _Button_1.title = [quiz objectAtIndex:r];

  // or better, i suggest you to use KVC
  // [self valueForKey:@"_Button_%d", i] setTitle //something like this.
  //
}
```